# C++ Cast increment cast

Tags: c++, casting

```
someobject* scratchpad[10000][33];
```

I want to do this in one statement:

```
unsigned int index = (int) scratchpad[j][0];    
scratchpad[j][0] = (someobject*) (index + 1);
```

I thought it was:

```
unsigned int index = (unsigned int) ++((char*)scratchpad)[j][0];
```

But I can't quite get the syntax right.  I'm actually storing an integer in the first (0) sub-array index.

Comment: what're you trying to do?

Comment: `I want to do this in one statement:`  Why?

Comment: Yes that `index` variable makes no sense.

Comment: don't store an integer in the first sub-array index.  Store it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't store an integer in the first sub-array index. Store it elsewhere.  Seriously.  Don't do this.**

But if you're an absolute maniac who's only goal is to make people hate you, then this works, on the assumption that an `unsigned int` is no bigger than a pointer.

```
unsigned index = ++reinterpret_cast<unsigned&>(scratchpad[j][0]);
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99043130e74913f9

Comment: I agree...on second thought, it's a terrible idea.  I was trying to optimize for performance, but it's just too cryptic.

Comment: @PentiumPro200: You'd be surprised how many performance optimizations like this make the program slower instead of faster.  Use faster _algorithms_, not faster code.  Write _simple_ code.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you're not telling us what your problem is. So I can only guess this is what you really need:

```
++scratchpad[j][0];
```

assuming `scratchpad` is just an array of pointers and you just want to increment one of them. If this is the case, you don't need a cast at all, so job done and all the ugly code is gone. Otherwise, you need to clarify, in words.

Answer (score -2):

I'm writing this as an answer and not a comment so (hopefully) the copious upvotes will convince you I am right.

```
 unsigned int index = (unsigned int) ++((char*)scratchpad)[j][0];
```

EVEN if that works (which it ought not....) **that is not what you should have** it is cryptic and hard to read.

2 lines is fine, although I'm not sure if you're ... what is some-object and an unsigned int...  I'll ask that in the comments.

Comment: I know its not your "fault" but why using c-style typecasts, why using pointers instead of references. Still, your answer has a valuable point, why trying to reduce code to a point where it becomes unreadable instead of making it as explicit as possible.

Comment: @Till yeah, that `someobject` and (int) cast had me worried too.